# Conversion function to_num

Tags: sql, oracle

Please show me an example for the `to_num` function. Convert charter to number. I am using Oracle

Comment: There is this thing called Google: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php

Comment: And more importantly, there is a thing called "the manual": https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions211.htm#SQLRF06140

Comment: Mind you, if they think it's the `to_num()` function they're need a bit of luck (or predictive text search) to find the documentation for `to_number()`

Answer (score 3):

TO_NUMBER( string1 [, format_mask] [, nls_language] )

see this document for more..
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php

from that :

Specially I think your answer is here :

```
TO_NUMBER('1210.73', '9999.99')
Result: 1210.73

TO_NUMBER('546', '999')
Result: 546

TO_NUMBER('23', '99')
Result: 23
```